# Is it possible to coalesce the same value?

Tags: sql-server, coalesce

I ran into this problem because I'm using grouping sets in a subquery that gives me this results

```
name    | objective | vehicle     | count_of_installed
------------------------------------------------------
Antonio |           |             | 1
Antonio | 40        | 2nd vehicle | 19
Antonio | NULL      | NULL        | 20
George  |           |             | 10
George  | 50        | 2nd vehicle | 20
George  | NULL      | NULL        | 30
```

And I'm then only searching only for rows where there are nulls, as they are the correct `count_of_installed`, now I want to have the correct `objective` and `vehicle` replacing the NULL values with the correct values, so I thought of something like `coalesce(objective, objective)`, but I'm not sure this works.

For reference, my `grouping sets` are:

```
grouping sets (name, (name, objective, vehicle))
```

**Edit 1**

In my example above is the result of a query with joining my `seller` and `sales` tables, it shouldn't show neither blank nor null values, so when I say `coalesce(objective, objective)`, I mean replace the null results from the result table with the correct values from my `seller` table.

Comment: `coalesce(objective, objective)` will still return `NULL`. `COALESCE` returns the next parameter when the former has `NULL`; and it "repeats" this process till it gets to a non-`NULL` value or runs out of parameters. If `objective` has the value `NULL`, then `objective` will have the value `NULL`, and the expression will return `NULL`; because all the parameters have the value `NULL`.

Comment: Instead, show us your full attempt, along with sample data and expected results. Help us help you.